# How to perform a java script in a UIWebview in iOS App with iOS 8?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I get a java script as a respond from NSUrlRequest. I want to show it in an UIWebView, but how to make this java script get to work? Thanks in advance.

Note that here I want to show some button in my java script which user can tap on to take some actions. Below is some of my code:

```
// get strContent as java script (respond from NSURLRequest)

// _myWebView is an instance of UIWebView

- (void) showWebContent:(NSString*)strContent {
  [self loadWebViewContent:strContent];
}

- (void) loadWebViewContent:(NSString*)strContent {

NSMutableString *htmlString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[htmlString appendFormat:@"<html> <body>"];
[htmlString appendFormat:@"%@",strContent];
[htmlString appendFormat:@"</body> </html>"];
[_webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `UIWebView`'s following method

```
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load webpage this way:

```
NSString* htmlString= @"<html><head><script> function func(){alert('Button Tapped');}</script></head><br><br><body align='center' bgcolor='green'><input type='button' onClick='func()' value='TAP ME'/></body></html>";

[self.webview loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

and then you can call any javascript function like this:

```
[self.webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"func()"];
```